# p-menuitem not a known element - primeng

Tags: angular, primeng, menubar, angular12

I'm new to primeng and having this difficulty. When I put a `p-menuitem` inside a `p-menubar`, angular gives me the following error:

```
'p-menuitem' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-menuitem' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-menuitem' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Now I understand that I need to add the module in app.module.ts which I did:

**app.module.ts code**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {MenubarModule} from 'primeng/menubar';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    MenubarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<p-menubar [model]="items">
   <p-menuitem>Any code here</p-menuitem>
</p-menubar>
```

I also imported the `MenubarModule` into the same component.ts as the HTML, the import line is faded though there. Is there something I'm missing here?

**Versions:**

```
"@angular/common": "~12.0.3"
"@angular/compiler": "~12.0.3"
"@angular/core": "~12.0.3"

"primeng": "12.0.0"
"primeicons": "4.1.0"
```

Comment: According to their [docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/menubar) it doesn't seem that there is a `p-menuitem` directive. Have you tried just this `<p-menubar [model]="items"></p-menubar>`? Can you also show us the content of the `items` property?

Comment: @DavidFontes `<p-menubar [model]="items"></p-menubar>` works as they have shown in the link that you've provided. It's the same code

Comment: Yes, I copied from their docs, but I'm confused, doesn't that fit your needs? If not, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Custom styling? Custom content?

Comment: I'm not sure if `p-menuitem` is a directive like `p-menubar` or just a pre-defined class as in `<label class="p-menuitem"></label>`

Comment: According to their docs, it is a css class for styling purposes.

Answer (score 1):

When using `Angular Language Service` extension in your Visual Studio Code, be sure to match the "View Engine" option to your version of Angular.

This can be done at the "Extensions" view, then clicking over the `Angular Language Server` item, then choosing "Extension Settings" at the cog icon ("Manage" button).

[image: "View Engine" option at "Angular Language Service" extension configurations]

For instance, when using Angular v12, **do not** check the "Use legacy View Engine language service" option, as newer versions of Angular have Ivy as their primary view engine. For older versions, you're supposed to check this option in order for the Language Server extension to work properly.

Please note that there might be multiple overlapping configurations at the same time, e.g. "User" + "Workspace". Especially when dealing with Remote Dev Containers, the extension seems to have a hard time reading the settings — for instance, in my case the specific settings in "Remote [Dev Container]" tab seem to have been completely ignored, so I had to override my "User" settings with unwanted settings in order for the warnings to desappear.

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found the solution here -> https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/showcase/components/menubar/menubardemo.module.ts

you must import MenubarModule in your component.module.ts and declare it in @NgModule -> imports

```
import { MenubarModule } from 'primeng/menubar';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MenubarModule
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is having difficulty with importing the [PrimeNG menubar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v14-lts/menubar), I'd like to add that the following line should go into the app.module.ts file.:

```
import { MenubarModule } from 'primeng/menubar';
```

And the following line should go into the app.component.ts file:

```
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/api';
```

It becomes clear when you follow the link into Stackblitz provided by the PrimeNG documentation:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-menubar-demo?file=README.md