# `p-menuItem` is not a known element

Tags: angular, menu, primeng

I am trying to use the following template:

```
<p-menu>
  <p-menuItem >Action</p-menuItem>
</p-menu>
```

However, this generates the following error:

```
error NG8001: 'p-menuItem' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-menuItem' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-menuItem' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

I have already imported MenuModule and MenuBar module, and none of them make this work. `p-menu` without `p-menuItem` works as expected, but my use case required `p-menuItem`.

I also already tried the things listed here: [p-menuitem not a known element - primeng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67904555/p-menuitem-not-a-known-element-primeng)

Comment: Which PrimeNG version you are currently used?

Comment: It seems there is not a directive/component for `p-menuItem`. You should pass the array into `[model]` for `<p-menu>` element.

Comment: According to the primeNG documentation, there is no such thing as `<p-menuItem>`. If you want to create a menu bar, you should use the `<p-menubar [model]="items"></p-menubar>` component. In your `component.ts` file, make sure to declare `items` as a list of `MenuItem[]` to properly configure the menu items.

https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fmenubar-basic-demo.ts